# How to change the font style in right header

Tags: header-footer

I want to change the font style in the right header. Currently it is in capital letters and also shows the chapter number in addition to the name as in the image below. I want to show only the name of the chapter in heading style i.e. the first letter of a word is capital and all others small. My MWE is attached.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\DeclareFixedFont{\chapternumberfont}{T1}{ppl}{m}{n}{1.5in}

\newcommand\brectangles{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\fill[red!60!blue!50!green!120]%[red!60!blue!50!green!150]% 
  (current page.north west) rectangle ( $ (current page.north east) + (0,-7cm) $);
\fill[red!60!blue!50!green!120]%[red!60!blue!50!green!150]% 
  (current page.south west) rectangle ( $ (current page.south east) + (0,3cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Large\bfseries\ssfamily\color{white}}%\scshape
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\brectangles}
  {-2in}
  {%
  \vskip-4ex\filcenter {\small\MakeUppercase{Project on Compilation of...}}\\[2ex]
  \parbox[b]{.65\linewidth}{#1}%
  \raisebox{0.8in}{\parbox{.15\linewidth}{\large\chaptertitlename}}%
  \parbox[b]{.2\linewidth}{\chapternumberfont\thechapter}%
  }
  [\vspace*{1in}]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries\color{white}} %sffamily\
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\brectangles} 
  {-2in}
  {\parbox[b]{.65\linewidth}{#1}}
  [\vspace*{1in}]


% for fancy header & footer
            \usepackage{xcolor}%
            \usepackage{fancyhdr}
                    \pagestyle{fancy}
                    \lhead{Statistics}
                    \lfoot{ LHS }
                    \rfoot{\includegraphics[width=20pt]{logo}}
                    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
                    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}


%for quotes
            \usepackage{csquotes}

% for hyperrefrences
\usepackage{url}
            \usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
                    \hypersetup{
                            colorlinks,
                            citecolor=black,
                            filecolor=black,
                            linkcolor=black,
                            urlcolor=blue
                                                }

% for line spacing
                    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

%for indenting paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

%for drop caps
            % works with pdfLaTeX
            \usepackage{type1cm} % scalable fonts
            \usepackage{lettrine}


% FOR CALLIGRAPHIC FONTS
            \usepackage{calligra}
            \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}


\begin{document}



\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{roman}

\pagestyle{empty}% no page numbers
\pagestyle{plain}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter {Introduction}
\chapter {Introduction}

\clearpage

\section{Right header is in capitals, how to change in normal font}

\section {Background}

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix-Workers' Remitances}

\section{Ahmad}

\section{Ahmad again}

\chapter{Ahmad yet again}

\section{Ahmad once more}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example *minimal*. That is not at all minimal and will not compile without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to redefine the `\rhead` command (which is responsible for putting something on the right-hand side of the header). You already have

```
\lhead{Statistics}
```

for the left-hand side, so just add the line

```
\rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
```

straight after it.

Source: [`fancyhdr` package documentation, section 9](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).

Comment: That only achieves one of the two desiderata, though, right? It doesn't touch the content of the mark.